# How to add JNDI destinations (Topics and Queues) with ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, jms, jndi, activemq-artemis

I don't want to use `jdni.properties` file, so to add new properties to my JNDI settings, I wrote following:

```java
    Hashtable<String, Object> jndi_env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    jndi_env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    jndi_env.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory","vm://0");
    jndi_env.put("topic.example","example");
```

My Problem is, when I call this class:

```java
initialContext = new InitialContext(jndi_env);
```

Since I pass a name parameter in the last line a URL context factory is looked up.

This makes my code looking for a `tcp://localhost:61616` connection which I actually don't want.

I see that there are

```
QueueConnectionFactory: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
example: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic
XAConnectionFactory: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory
```

which I don't want, or at least not the type they are.

If I check without passing an argument using my `jndi.properties` file where I don't get the issue of establishing a tcp connection, then I find just:

```java
ConnectionFactory: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory
queue: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ReadOnlyContext
queue/exampleQueue: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue
dynamicTopics: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory$2
dynamicQueues: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory$1
```

So how can I change the object types of my added `jndi_env.put("topic.example","example");` so it will be like this (but of course for Topics)

```java
queue: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ReadOnlyContext
queue/exampleQueue: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `InitialContext` you're passing in the wrong factory. Currently you're passing in `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`. This is the factory for ActiveMQ 5.x, not Artemis. You need to pass in `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` instead, e.g.:

```java
Hashtable<String, Object> jndi_env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
jndi_env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
jndi_env.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory","vm://0");
jndi_env.put("topic.example","example");
```